# Is it possible to edit the text stored at the top of the page and just insert a variable name where I want the text pasted in html for a blog website

Tags: python, html, css

I am trying to make a blog but without a complex backend using HTML

How can I store the article using a variable and just use that variable name where I want the text pasted, instead of every time I want to post/ edit having to scroll all the way to find it.

something like in python where you can have a variable and edit it.
or is it possible to implement python into the html for this ?

I have tried searching on youtube and google but can't find anything

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this - where you just pre-write your template, and then get python to dynamically add the text you want into the template like this:

```py
dynamic_text = "Here is my new title"

html = f"<div><h1>{dynamic_text}</h1></div>"
print(html)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
<div><h1>Here is my new title</h1></div>
```